# Sub Menu Sensitive In Chrome But Fine In Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, menu

I'm only a year in to Web Design. I've been learning menus at Lynda.com and specifically have a problem creating a sub menu.

I've made the sub menu how I want it, however when I flick between the list items on my menu they change over too quickly.

See on the picture below:

http://s22.postimg.org/699f35hm9/macca_travel.png

If you look at the position of the cursor, it is still on the 'About' tab, but the 'Blog' hover has lit up and has been selected.

The two sections with sub menus are the 'Blog' tab and the 'Photos' tab. These two tabs don't cross over smoothly and I think it's because for whatever reason they're selecting too quickly.

I don't know why :)

Here is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'telegraficoregular';
    src: url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.svg#telegraficoregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

.cf:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

html, body, head, nav, article, aside, section, h3, h4, footer, ul, li {

margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

/*Global Styles*/

html {

background: white;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}


body {

width: 100%;
height: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
background: white;
font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
font-size: 16px;
color: black;

}

h1 {

font-family: telegraficoregular;
font-size: 3em;
color: white;
padding: 0;
margin:0;
text-align: center;

}

h2 {

font-family: telegraficoregular;
font-size: 1em;
font-style: italic;
color: white;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;

}

p {

font-family: serif;
font-size: 1.1em;
color: black;
text-align:left;
padding-left:70px;
}

h4 + p {

font-family: serif;
font-size: 1.1em;
color: black;
text-align:left;
padding-left:70px;
padding-top: 10px;
}
/*Nav Styles */

header {

background:#6593b5;
width: 100%;
height: 160px;
margin:0 auto;

}

nav {

background: black;
height: 2em;

}

nav ul li {

float: left;


}

nav ul li a {

display: block;
padding:0 2em;
line-height: 2em;
color: white;
font-family: telegraficoregular;
text-decoration: none;
}

li, ul {

position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

}

ul.SubMenu {

float: none;
width: auto;
height: auto;
list-style: none;
background: black;
color: white;
position: absolute;
left: -9000em;
}

ul.SubMenu li{

float: none;

}

ul.SubMenu li a{

display:block;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
padding: .2em 2em;
white-space: nowrap;

}

li:hover ul {

left: 0;

}

li:hover ul {

left: 0;

}

/* Article Styles */

article {

width: 896px;
padding: 32px;

}


/*Section Styles */


section.China {

text-align: center;
margin: 80px auto;
padding: 20px;

}

section h3 {

font-family: telegraficoregular;
font-size: 2em;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}

section h4 {

font-family: telegraficoregular;
font-size: 1.4em;
padding-top: 60px;
padding-left: 70px;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: underline;

}

section.China img {

position: relative;
top: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

section.Australia {

text-align: center;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 20px;

}

section.Australia img {

position: relative;
top: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

section.Thailand {

text-align: center;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 20px;

}

section.Thailand img {

position: relative;
top: 20px;
border-radius: 5px;
}


/* Link Styles*/

a:hover {

color: orange;
height: 32px;
background: black;

}

ul.SubMenu li a:hover {

background: orange;
color: white;

}

/* About Styles */



#AboutContent{

width: 960px;
height: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
background: white;
font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
font-size: 16px;
color: black;

}

#AboutHeader {

text-align: center;
margin: 20px auto;
padding: 20px;

}

#AboutHeader img {

display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;

}

#AboutHeader h2 {

font-family: telegraficoregular;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-decoration: underline;
color: black;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center;

}

h2 + img {

position: relative;
top: 50px;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#AboutHeader p {

font-family: serif;
font-size: 1.1em;
color: black;
text-align:left;
padding:50px 0 0 100px;
}

/*Photos Content */

#PhotoContent{

width: 960px;
height:auto;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
background: white;
font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
font-size: 16px;
color: black;

}

/* Photos Gallery */

#ChinaPhotos {

width: 960px;
height:1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
background: white;
font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
font-size: 16px;
color: black;

}

#ChinaPhotos h3 {

font-family: telegraficoregular;
font-size: 2em;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
margin-top: 20px;

}

#ChinaPhotos img {

margin-top: 20px;
border: 1px solid black;

}

#ChinaPhotos a .Thumb:hover {

width: 320px;
height: 240px;

}

/* Container Styles */

#Content {

width: 960px;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
background: white;
font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
font-size: 16px;
color: black;

}


/* Footer Styles */

.Footer {
width: 100%;
height: 160px;
background: black;
}

.Footer p {

font-family: telegraficoregular;
color: white;
font-style: italic;
line-height: 160px;
text-align: center;

}
```

Thanks Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to each section of your CSS:

```
ul.SubMenu {
    margin-top: 2em;
}

nav ul li a {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hey man, 

that worked!

What was I doing wrong and what was happening before?

Also... why did I have to add display:block to the list item as it's already a block level element?

Thanks again!

Comment: The padding on each li item was overlapping for some reason. So, I simply removed the overlap by floating it left and displaying it as a block.

If this worked for you, click this as the correct answer, so it's clear you question is answered.

Comment: Done!

One last thing... I've just noticed there seems to be an overlap on the right of the submenu list items..

see here:

http://s12.postimg.org/skjdkjrrh/overlap.png

weirdly this only happens on the photo sub menu and not the blog one.

Comment: Try adding width: 100%; to the submenu like items. If that fails, comment with a live link, I'll look.

Comment: Didn't work mate. I haven't got the site live as I'm just practising at the moment. I'm a little confused as why it's doing it to one submenu and not the other as they're the same styles.

I'll try figure it out on my own!

Thanks again :)